# Script doesn't change "href" and "div" content depending on the current URL

Tags: javascript, html, wordpress

I have a NavMenu present on all pages of my site which is a table with images that refer you to their product pages. I am trying to write a script which changes these links and the names that appear under the images depending on which language the site is being viewed in, but it's not working. I've changed the names and the links to serve as an example, but fundamentally it's the same thing. I am using Wordpress and i've tried putting the script both in the "header.php" and using the "Scripts n Styles" plugin. Also i'm fairly new to JavaScript so don't hold back on any criticism that might help me in the future.

This is the HTML of the table where the pictures of products with links reside, I've removed most of them for easier reading:

```
<table style=width:100%>
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td><a id="LinkToProduct" href=www.example.com/lt/product><img class="productIconImage" src="www.example.com/uploads/productimage.png/>
        <div class="productIconName" id="ProductName">Product name in lithuanian</div>
        </a>
      </td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

This is the script I have written:

```
<script>
      (function changeMainProductNavLinks() {
          var currentUrl = location.href;
          var parts = location.href.split("/");
          if (parts[1] == "eng") {
            //Changing of the div text and href links.
            document.getElementById("LinkToProduct").href = "www.example.com/eng/product"; 

            // Changing the url to english language site
            document.getElementById("ProductName").innerHTML = "Product name in english";
       })() 
</script>
```

Comment: Where is the script located? Is there error in the console? My guess parts[1] is not what you think it is.

Comment: Where you include your script in HTML?

Comment: There are no errors that appear anywhere. Currently I have it put after the table HTML in the Header.php file.

Comment: Try to include your script in the end of the <body>

Comment: I've tried that with the Scripts n Styles plugin, no effect.

Answer (score 2):

```
document.getElementById("").setAttribute("href", "http://....");
```

Try this way.

Comment: Will do in a moment.

Comment: No luck, still no change

Comment: I tried my code and it works with changing attribute href.. Maybe you have other mistake in giving link to your function.

Comment: Quite peculiar. Well I'll try to muck around with the variables and if I solve this then I'll post the answer. Still, I appreciate your help.

Comment: When I look at your code I see that your link starts with www and it can cause problem.. Try with http://

Comment: Also see what console says.

Comment: Now that i've checked, it says "Uncaught SyntaxError: missing ) after argument list"

Comment: Ok it was a syntax error when i put the arguments in your suggested line, i forgot to put a ")" after the arguments. But now it says "Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token )"

Comment: See where in your code is this exception. In which line and correct it.

Answer (score 2):

Alright, I've finally figured it out. The problem was that I didn't put a second "}" to end the function, only one to end the "if" statements. That was the problem all along, and now it's working fine. Thanks to everyone who tried to help

Answer (score 0):

`window.location.href` includes `http://` in it so `parts[1]` is going to be an empty string.

You probably want to use `window.location.pathname` or change the index to account for `http://`

Comment: Actually I have tried to to change the array to parts[3], but also no effect. Will try it with "window.location.pathname" though

Answer (score 0):

Change your script to this

```
<script>
      (function changeMainProductNavLinks() {
          var currentUrl = location.href;
          var parts = currentUrl.replace(/.*\//g,'').replace(/\?.*/g,'');
          if (parts == "eng") {
            //Changing of the div text and href links.
            document.getElementById("LinkToProduct").href = "www.example.com/eng/product"; 

            // Changing the url to english language site
            document.getElementById("ProductName").innerHTML = "Product name in english";
       }})() 
</script>
```